# Using str.replace for list of list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

```
x =  ['[1867, 1868]', '[6612663]']
```

Expected Output:

```
x =  [[1867, 1868], [6612663]]
```

I tried ,

```
x = [item.replace("'", "") for item in x]
```

It didn't work.

Could someone help?

Comment: Are you trying to parse stringified lists of integers into actual lists of integers? Please clarify.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, the input list has been created from the keys of a dictionary. So the keys(lists) are stored as strings. It is not a duplicate of the other question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Does the duplicate suggestion solve the problem? It seems you can do a list comprehension, so you can combine the two techniques `[ast.literal_eval(e) for e in x]` or `map(ast.literal_eval, x)` for an iterator. I recommend searching the website thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, it solves my problem. Sorry I didn't know about ast.literal and I didn't search with those keywords

Comment: That's OK, it happens. I searched google for "python convert string list to list" to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import ast

x =  ['[1867, 1868]', '[6612663]']
new = [ast.literal_eval(ls) for ls in x]
print(new)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [[1867, 1868], [6612663]]
> ```

Comment: @ggorlen :D typo